# how to update two aggregate in a transaction with using an event

Tags: events, transactions, aggregate, domain-driven-design, cqrs

To clarify, I simplified my problem. I used DDD approach and CQRS pattern.
In my application I have 2 aggregates User and Contact and have two entry points to add a user or contact. Everything was fine until my customer said I need a new API entry point to add a user and a contact together in the same time.

I wrote a new command for both of them, but found out I could not use a command for more than one duty and have to use events. On the other hand, in DDD approach, an aggregate root can raise events. In this case it does not make sense to raise an event by user because it does not know about contact.

In my opinion, application layer is in charge of raise event. Also, how to persist both of them in a transaction and how to send UserId to contact command. I am so confused how to solve it.

I was wondering if you could provide me a solution or way to solve.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregates should not talk to other aggregates and only commands trigger a change in an aggregate. The alternative is to have some saga/process manager that listens for events and raises commands against other aggregates.

I would keep using two commands and instead "fake it" in the user-interface as one option.

But then the question what is a User? and what is a contact? Is a user someone who can login? or customer user? do you really create a user and a contact at the same time?

Comment: thanks for advice.
do you say, I make a fake command and publish a message with two request(add user, add contact) then saga manage commands.
In real project user is party aggregate(actor or role, identity, contact, address) and contact is relationship aggregate.

Comment: what about a transaction can I update two commands in a transaction or violate the aggregate rules.

Comment: No, you can only update one aggregate per command, its a transactional boundary. I mean your UI could issue two commands to the backend, to make what the customer wants from you. The UI can send multiple commands, but you need to be careful because if one command fail and one command succeed, you will have some problems. Often when you have these problems, its a sign that you have modelled your domain wrong.

Comment: I do not think this problem stem from design. Relationship must be a separate  aggregate because of large amount of data. In some cases relationship could be more than 10000 per party. I think it is better I stick to handle transactions problem.
Finally, thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: I also think its important to realize that some aggregates are not suitable to be event-sourced and sometimes will work better as stored in a relational-way. you can still have commands/queries and CQRS using a classic relational database.

Comment: Also, some data perhaps does not belong in an aggregate, like click-data, visits to web page, or other event data. Storing this kind of data directly in a database like Kafka or a classic relational table is a better idea.